# Update loaded value with node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, appjs

Express view:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index", { addons: addons });
});
```

Jade template loop

```
each addon in addons
```

How would update that addons loop after the initial load using appjs/node.js/express/jade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to write some AJAX code. The way you'd do it might look something like this:

app.get('/addons', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ addons: addons });
});

Then, in your jade template, write some code which makes an AJAX request to your /addons URL, parses the JSON response, then loops over it.